# Object destructuring with default values from two similar interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces, `User` and `BankUser`. The interface for `BankUser` is roughly as follows:

```js
interface BankUser extends User {
  banks: { [bank_id: string]: string};
  isSuper: boolean;
}
```

I have a function where I'm going to pass in either a `User` or a `BankUser` and I want a `BankUser` to come out of it. If it's a User, it should add the default properties for `BankUser`.

```js
const cleanedUser = (user: User | BankUser): BankUser => {
  const {uid, displayName, email, phoneNumber, photoURL, banks = {}, isSuper = false} = user;
  return {uid, displayName, email, phoneNumber, photoURL, banks, isSuper} as BankUser;
}
```

I get two TS2339 errors indicating that banks and isSuper does not exist on type `User | BankUser`, for example:

> TS2339: Property 'banks' does not exist on type `User | BankUser`

If I add `// @ts-ignore` above the function, it works and I can send either a `User` or a `BankUser`, but I try to avoid that if at all possible. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Your error refers to a type `IUser`, but this type is not defined in this code.

Comment: @kaya3 Whoops. Thanks for catching that. The actual naming conventions used are a little convoluted, so I changed them in the example to be a little more clear. That's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't like looking up a property of an object if it's not explicitly mentioned in the object's type.  In this case, `User` doesn't explicitly mention `banks` or `isSuper`, so you get a compiler error.  Yes, a `BankUser` does have such a property, but `user` might be a `User` and so it's an error.

If you want to convince the compiler to look up the property, you need to treat `user` as something more specific than `User | BankUser`.  For example, you can treat it like `User & Partial<BankUser>`.  That type is known to have all of `User`'s properties, and *optionally* the extra properties from `BankUser`.  That gives you this:

```
const cleanedUser = (user: User | BankUser): BankUser => {
    const {
        uid, displayName, email, phoneNumber, photoURL, banks = {}, isSuper = false
    } = user as User & Partial<BankUser>; // no error now
    return { uid, displayName, email, phoneNumber, photoURL, banks, isSuper };
}
```

Also, depending on your use case, I might implement `cleanedUser` like this instead:

```
const cleanedUser2 = (user: User | BankUser): BankUser => {
    return { banks: {}, isSuper: false, ...user };
}
```

That requires less type manipulation and less typing.  It has the same behavior as `cleanedUser` if you assume that the value passed in for `user` is *exactly* a `User` or a `BankUser` and has no extra properties.

---

Once you expect that `user` might have extra properties then you might need to be more careful with both `cleanedUser()` or `cleanedUser2()`'s implementations, since a value of type `User` might have, say, an extra `isSuper` property of type `number`.  That's a perfectly valid `User` but you'd see weird things happen when you do your cleaning:

```
interface Hmm extends User {
    isSuper: number;
}
const hmm: Hmm = {
    uid: "", email: "", displayName: "", phoneNumber: "", photoURL: "", isSuper: 100
};
const beCareful = cleanedUser(hmm);
console.log(beCareful.isSuper) // boolean at compile time, number at runtime !!!
```

So be careful.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHICuwAJgFzLphSgDmANPoacOgA4A2cAngHJwAthErVaIRswIRBcYJ1E16TQsnYALAPYgIfIoIBG0ReMmqNmsJtQAlADInluAL65coSLEQoAQnBAA1hhYEAAekCCk6GiYUDhSyAb+AeiU2MgA2kmBAPpkjhIAugV0yM4A3AlsAMpE7MaJmpqcEP6VrrgI2tTICC3+EKTBcQC8yAAURLGUw8gAPsh+gcMAlJRLQbHIIwB88apdID14qqokpAzIrBzc-EIQlzJynJcWOnqG0K9aVrZ2l9kUtscM5LjU6lgxvBOJgEs5gVMsHBorMAGTIAAKcCgYGAcE4AB4NsMduVkAB6cnIECaZDQKCaOI0gDuCSgEDARCgIBwxDIl2uXF4AmEj1k8m+2l0+iMUElv3sAOS6DB6Fq9TiFRcbkOPT6rR0Q1iACZgZNpjEsAtibE1otkrNdvtCOzOdzeYDUiDVeqGtDMJcAHTBxGa9pudzgaDwJDIAASgkEdPCEEiKK2J0I4I1lBAMug4d1YGQ6kTlATSbGmYI50oACI62LnvXG1c2EK7sIW5L3vmoN21D9rPYB9mGgBGAAMk5clSLiQgAGFsRAYEROMD9QMjdBxqXBCs591mhBA5xNHRxkZl+y15xA2OoCsKVSDE1+jy4MWuoJ2PIULiorUn2yBfsgUBEOAwDCMgACE8ERhGQA)

Comment: Thanks. Part of the reason why I'm so verbose in the cleanedUser function is  that I'm using it like lodash.pick() to remove any unwanted properties as well. I had tried Partial<User | BankUser>, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Interesting...using (user: Partial<User & BankUser>) doesn't show any errors. I guess that makes sense...I think that's the route I'm going to take for now. Thanks for digging into this!